# Error al recargar la pagina en Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7

he subido un proyecto en Angular 7 y todo perfecto pero cuando se refresca la pagina o la recargas la pagina da error o se queda en blanco, he conseguido solucionar este problema añadiendo estas lineas al .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

por ejemplo si mi web es https://agustin.com/ y tengo una url de 1 nivel que es https://agustin.com/videojuegos y recargo la pagina con el código que he metido en .htaccess me recarga perfecto sin errores pero si hay lo mismo en una URL de 2 niveles por ejemplo https://agustin.com/videojuegos/god-of-war cuando recargo la pagina me da error 404 o se queda en blanco y en la consola me muestra este error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.20ab2d163684112c2aba.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
scripts.ecbf1e4e445943032e3d.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.5de7abb27a3f7daa0ce1.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
outsider-demigod:11 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://agustin.com/videojuegos/assets/css/admin.css".
outsider-demigod:13 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://agustin.com/videojuegos/styles.9fa82bc53e2292902fdb.css".
```

No consigo solucionar este problema.

Comment: Hola. `/videojuegos` es el directorio donde está alojada la aplicación o hace parte del routing definido en Angular?

Comment: Es una ruta de angular. || Donde esta la aplicación es aquí https://agustin.com/ en la raiz

Comment: Esta bien la solución para en error 404 en pc ,pero en móviles sigue pasando lo mismo tienes anguna idea de que puede estar pasando??? ayuda !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Es un error típico al momento de copilar angular pierde las rutas de navegación, una forma sencilla de resolverlo es agregando las siguientes lineas a tu app.module.ts en la sección de provider

```
providers: [
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
],
```

Luego importas la librería

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

Ya con esto al navegar vas a observar que a la url se va adicionar un (#) con esto puedes recargar la pagina.